# Default arguments in overloaded methods

Tags: scala

I am wondering why it is not allowed for multiple overloaded methods to have default parameters (when it is not ambiguous), and, more importantly, if someone can think of a workaround for that restriction.

Here is some background. I am using this trick to distinguish between primitive types and references:

```
def toJson[T](writer: Writer, data: T)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyVal = null) {
  val wrapped = (Option(ev), data) match {
    case (Some(_), _) | (_, _:String) => Map("result" -> data)
    case _ => data
  }
  jsonMapper.writeValue(writer, data)
}
```

When `T` is a primitive type, `ev` is not null, and I can wrap the data into a `Map` to produce valid json rather than just printing out a raw value.
This works, but the problem is that I need to have different flavors of this function. For example:

```
def toJson[T](out: OutputStream, data: T)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyVal = null) =
  toJson(new OutputStreamWriter(out), data)
def toJson(data: T)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyVal = null) = {
  val w = new StringWriter
  toJson(w, data)
  w.toString
}
```

etc ...
Unfortunately, this does not compile, because overloaded functions cannot all have default arguments for some reason. I cannot think of a good reason why this cannot be allowed, and am curious about the rationale for such restriction. More importantly, as I said above, if someone can recommend another way to do what I am trying to do here (other than coming up with 15 different yet meaningful names for one function), I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/FyQK3-cqfaY/fXLHr8QsW_0J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest alternative would be to use this helper method:

```
import scala.reflect._
def isPrimitive[T:ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].erasure.isPrimitive
```

Then:

```
def toJson[T:ClassTag](writer: Writer, data: T) {
  val wrapped = if (isPrimitive[T]) Map("result" -> data) else data
  jsonMapper.writeValue(writer, wrapped)
}
```

No default value, so no problem with overloading.

Be aware though that this solution has slightly different semantics than your original code. With the above code, "primitive" really means primitive in the JVM sense (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3), while with your code, value classes (even value classes wrapping non-primitive types as per the JVM spec) are considered "primitive".

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I made a minor edit to make it compile, but overall looks like a good idea. Don't know why I haven't thought of it myself ...

Comment: Just a side note: if you import `scala.reflect._`, it does compile as is (the package contains both the `ClassTag` type and a `classTag` method to perform the lookup). That was not a typo :-)